# Use of "neither" and "nor" in thesis dedication

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

I am including a dedication page in my thesis with the following dedication:

*"To my parents Jack and Jill, and brother Jerry. This journey would neither have been possible nor worthwhile without your endless love and support."*

I'm just wondering if the second sentence is grammatically correct? (I am not a native English speaker)

Comment: It is perfectly alright. You can even consider writing: _This journey would have been neither possible nor worthwhile without your endless love and support._

Comment: It's a matter of personal style whether you use ***your*** or ***their** [support]* in your dedication. (Do you see the dedication as being addressed specifically to them, or to all your readers?) Or you could slightly "sidestep" the issue, as many have done before you, by phrasing it as *To [Tom, Dick, and Harry] **without whose** endless love and support this journey would not...* Personally, I'd move ***neither*** forward to immediately before ***possible***, to give slightly more focus/emphasis, but that's just another stylistic choice.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice/ideas @DhanishthaGhosh and @FumbleFingers!

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I may be pedantic, but I am also wondering if the "...nor worthwhile" part is redundant? (Something that is "not possible" could obviously not be anything else). I didn't want to say the same thing that thousands of people have said in the past, so I wanted to change it a bit haha.

Comment: I think that "or worthwhile" bit is rather charming, actually! Sorry if I'm "raining on your parade", but I couldn't resist searching in Google Books for "**possible nor worthwhile**" - where the very first result (or *many*) returned is a dedication by some author Andrés Hatum: *Finally, without the love and unconditional support of my wife and my son this journey would neither have been possible nor worthwhile....*

Comment: ... And (I swear I'm not making this up! I hadn't even looked at Google Books, let alone seen anything like this when I posted my first comment above! :) the *second* result returned by my search just now is *It would be **neither possible nor worthwhile** to attempt to prevent “**every Tom, Dick and Harry**” from issuing his own personal fatwas*.

Comment: Haha, what a wonderful find! I will leave in the "...nor worthwhile" part :)
Thanks!

Comment: ["The problem with Islam is every Tom Dick and Harry can give fatwah!"](https://youtu.be/mMraxhd9Z9Q?t=3348) Again, I swear I'm not making it up! I just couldn't ignore hearing the moderator say that in this Christopher Hitchens debate I happened to be watching!